# Unexpected binary sequences in Postscript generated by Canon printer driver

Tags: printing, driver, postscript

We are having issues with the Postscript code generated by the "Canon iR-ADV C5235/5240 PS3" printer driver. We print a test document (3 A4 pages of Lorem Ipsum text) and get the following Postscript output in the Windows spool directory:

http://files.etvdzs.info/original.ps

We have tried various Postscript viewers/converters, and they are unable to handle this file. The reason is that the file contains sections of binary data at the beginning and end, and also the following byte sequence at position 0x1060b:

```
cd ca 10 02 00 1a 00 01 82 6f ff ff 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 01
```

If we remove these three binary sequences, we get the resulting file, which works fine in most Postscript viewers/converters we have tried:

http://files.etvdzs.info/cleaned.ps

Has anybody else encountered similar issues with Canon printer drivers? Does anybody know what these binary sequences signify, or what format they are in?

Answer (score 3):

The binary sequences are CPCA codes. One can download documentation about the data structures used in CPCA after registering here:

https://www.developersupport.canon.com/user/register

It is then reasonably straightforward to write a program that strips the CPCA codes out of the file. The file can then be loaded successfully by 3rd-party Postscript viewers/converters.